# Stateful tail (only shows the new lines from the last execution)

Tags: perl, tail, persistent, stateful

I want to be able to see how many lines were added to a file since the last quering without reading the whole file again.

Something like :

```
ptail my_file | fgrep "[ERROR]" | wc -l
```

A solution in simple Perl would be prefered, since I don't have an easy access to a compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it consumed the lines for other purposes, I have written code which does essentially this before.

All you need to do is record the byte offset (with **tell**) and inode (with **stat**) for each file after the tail is complete.  The next time it's run against the file, first check the inode (with **stat**) again.  If the inode has changed or the file is smaller than the recorded offset, then it's a different file (deleted and recreated, log got rotated, etc.), so you should show it from the beginning; otherwise, **seek** to the recorded offset and display it from there.

Answer (score 2):

[since](http://welz.org.za/projects/since) does exactly that although it is in C.

Answer (score 2):

May be this Perl package can help you:

[File::Tail::Multi](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/module/File::Tail::Multi)

Derived from MultiTail, this perl library makes it easy to tail a dynamic list of files and match/except lines using full regular expressions and even maintains their state locally.

EXAMPLE use File::Tail::Multi;

```
$tail1=File::Tail::Multi->new (  OutputPrefix => "f", 
                                 Debug => "$True", 
                                 Files => ["/var/adm/messages"]
                              );
while(1) {
    $tail1->read;
    #
    $tail1->print;
    sleep 10;
}
```

- `$tail1=File::Tail::Multi->new` : Create new ptail object
- `Files` => Tail file /var/adm/messages
- `OutputPrefix` => Prepend the name of the file beginning of each line in object attribute "LineArray"
- `$tail1->read` : Read all line from files
- `$tail1->print` : Print all line in object attribute "LineArray";

Comment: That's *got* to be the perl answer!

Comment: Here the state is maintained, but only in one execution of the program.
I would like the state to be saved across program executions.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a minimal version of a pure Perl version :

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# Perl clone of since(1)
# http://welz.org.za/projects/since
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw/ SEEK_SET O_RDWR O_CREAT /;
use NDBM_File;

my $state_file = "$ENV{HOME}/.psince";

my %states;
tie(%states, 'NDBM_File', $state_file, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0660)
        or die("cannot tie state to $state_file : $!");

while (my $filename = shift) {
        if (! -r $filename) {
                # Ignore
                next;
        }
        my @file_stats = stat($filename);
        my $device = $file_stats[0];
        my $inode = $file_stats[1];
        my $size = $file_stats[7];
        my $state_key = $device . "/" .$inode;
        print STDERR "state_key=$state_key\n";

        if (! open(FILE, $filename) ) {
                print STDERR "cannot open $filename : $!";
                next;
        }

        # Reverting to the last cursor position
        my $offset = $states{$state_key} || 0;
        if ($offset <= $size) {
                sysseek(FILE, $offset, SEEK_SET);
        } else {
                # file was truncated, restarting from the beginning
                $offset = 0;
        }

        # Reading until the end
        my $buffer;
        while ((my $read_count = sysread(FILE, $buffer, 4096)) > 0) {
                $offset += $read_count;
                print $buffer;
        }
        # Nothing to read
        close(FILE);
        $states{$state_key} = $offset;
}

# Sync the states
untie(%states);
```

@Dave: It's almost like your algorithm, except that i don't use **tell**, but an internal maintained counter.